# count of converted array of JSON

Tags: javascript

I convert a PHP array with `json_encode()` in PHP 
then I give that JSON array in javascript and convert that to a javascript array 
with `JSON.parse()` now this codes is work

```
alert(arr[0]); alert(arr[1])  and other giving array value like this alert(arr[2])
```

but this codes not work

```
arr.length; and arr.size()
```

array content when converted with `json_ecnode()` in php

```
{"0":"sdg","1":"gds","2":"hdf","4":"hdsf","5":"gsvd","6":"sdggds","7":"sdgsdggdsdsgg","10":";dsg"}
```

Excuse me: sorry for my grammar in English, my native language is not English

Comment: If it's an array, it's just `arr.length`

Comment: Can you attach your array content to be sure that you have the correct format?

Comment: @Keith Thanks for your help but that's not work

Comment: Can you post what your JSON looks like?

Comment: If it was an associative array, it won't be an array in JS it will be an object, hence why you wouldn't get a `.length` call to work. Though a `Object.keys(parsedData).length` should have

Comment: @zelda7 thanks for your comment , I attach content of array

Comment: Yea that is an object, you can tell as it has `{ }` where if it was an actual array it would have been `[ ]`

Comment: Try capitalizing Object in `Object.keys(arr).length`

Comment: @PatrickEvans thanks for your help Object.keys(parsedData).length works object.keys(arr).length not worked when I used

Comment: `object` should be `Object`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.length would be for arrays, for this object that you have attached, you can use this:

```
Object.keys(arr).length
```

It counts the keys in the object.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

vanilla **javascript**:

```js
var myjson={"0":"sdg","1":"gds","2":"hdf","4":"hdsf","5":"gsvd","6":"sdggds","7":"sdgsdggdsdsgg","10":";dsg"};
var myjson_lenth = Object.keys(myjson).length;
console.log(myjson_lenth);
```

**JQuery**:

```js
var myjson={"0":"sdg","1":"gds","2":"hdf","4":"hdsf","5":"gsvd","6":"sdggds","7":"sdgsdggdsdsgg","10":";dsg"};
var myjson_lenth = $.map(myjson, function(n, i) { return i; }).length;
console.log(myjson_lenth);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```